# Can we have start event outside of a pool?

Tags: activiti, bpmn

Can we have a start event outside of a pool? None of the examples I've seen so far have the start event *outside* a pool (it always starts from a circle inside one of the lanes in the pool).

Here's my process diagram in Activiti. I would like to know if Activiti would accept and execute a model like this one:

[image]

Thanks in advance,
Raka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. But if your example is your real case, you don't need to do that, you can use [message start event](http://activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnMessageStartEvent).

> A message start event can be used to start a process instance using a
>   named message. This effectively allows us to select the right start
>   event from a set of alternative start events using the message name.

It would be cleaner that your lanes have own start event.

Comment: Agree, you should put a start message event in each lane. It would be a cleaner flow and gets rid of the message event conditional gateway.

Answer (score 0):

At least in Activiti: it is executable. The easiest way to validate is create a simple process definition like this one below, and try to execute it using sequence of REST calls.

[image]